# Javascript pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a bunch of CSS and SVG elements that get placed into a div and I would like the user to be able to pan and zoom around to all of them. I am using the library from [Jquery Panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom). Is there a way to contain it so that if the user has an element outside of the viewport they will be able to pan to the edge of the container with all of the elements inside of it?

Below I will provide an example of what it's doing now. When it is all zoomed in and there is still an element not seen, I would like to be able to pan to the other element.

[image: Still pan]

When Everything is seen, I would like it to not be able to pan but still zoom.
[image: When seen]

When it is zoomed all of the ways out, I would like the container to be the width of the viewport. The problem I am having is that if I set the container to be the width of the viewport at its most zoomed out level. It decides to hide below the viewport.

[image]
**Example**

[Example using Panzoom](https://codepen.io/NaszvadiG/pen/BRQMyy)

**Code from codepen**

**Html**

```
<div id="chart_container">
  <div class="flowchart-example-container" id="example"></div>
</div>
<div class="draggable_operators">
  <div class="draggable_operators_label">
    Operators (drag and drop them in the flowchart):
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_operators_divs">
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="1" data-nb-outputs="0">1 input</div>
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="0" data-nb-outputs="1">1 output</div>
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="1" data-nb-outputs="1">1 input &amp; 1 output</div>
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="1" data-nb-outputs="2">1 in &amp; 2 out</div>
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="2" data-nb-outputs="1">2 in &amp; 1 out</div>
    <div class="draggable_operator" data-nb-inputs="2" data-nb-outputs="2">2 in &amp; 2 out</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="delete_selected_button">Delete selected operator / link</button>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #666;
}

#chart_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #eee, #eee 10px, #e5e5e5 10px, #e5e5e5 20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flowchart-example-container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#example {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background: white;
}

.draggable_operators_label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.draggable_operators_divs {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.draggable_operator {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: grab;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $flowchart = $('#example');
  var $container = $flowchart.parent();

  var cx = $flowchart.width() / 2;
  var cy = $flowchart.height() / 2;

  // Panzoom initialization...
  $flowchart.panzoom();

  // Centering panzoom
  $flowchart.panzoom('pan', -cx + $container.width() / 2, -cy + $container.height() / 2);

  // Panzoom zoom handling...
  var possibleZooms = [0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 3];
  var currentZoom = 2;
  $container.on('mousewheel.focal', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = (e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) || e.originalEvent.detail;
    var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    currentZoom = Math.max(0, Math.min(possibleZooms.length - 1, (currentZoom + (zoomOut * 2 - 1))));
    $flowchart.flowchart('setPositionRatio', possibleZooms[currentZoom]);
    $flowchart.panzoom('zoom', possibleZooms[currentZoom], {
      animate: false,
      focal: e
    });
  });

  var data = {
    operators: {
      operator1: {
        top: cy - 100,
        left: cx - 200,
        properties: {
          title: 'Operator 1',
          inputs: {},
          outputs: {
            output_1: {
              label: 'Output',
            }
          }
        }
      },
      operator2: {
        top: cy,
        left: cx + 140,
        properties: {
          title: 'Operator 2',
          inputs: {
            input_1: {
              label: 'Input 1',
            },
            input_2: {
              label: 'Input 2',
            },
          },
          outputs: {}
        }
      },
    },
    links: {
      link_1: {
        fromOperator: 'operator1',
        fromConnector: 'output_1',
        toOperator: 'operator2',
        toConnector: 'input_2',
      },
    }
  };

  // Apply the plugin on a standard, empty div...
  $flowchart.flowchart({
    data: data,
    linkWidth: 5
  });

  $flowchart.parent().siblings('.delete_selected_button').click(function() {
    $flowchart.flowchart('deleteSelected');
  });

  var $draggableOperators = $('.draggable_operator');

  function getOperatorData($element) {
    var nbInputs = parseInt($element.data('nb-inputs'));
    var nbOutputs = parseInt($element.data('nb-outputs'));
    var data = {
      properties: {
        title: $element.text(),
        inputs: {},
        outputs: {}
      }
    };

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nbInputs; i++) {
      data.properties.inputs['input_' + i] = {
        label: 'Input ' + (i + 1)
      };
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nbOutputs; i++) {
      data.properties.outputs['output_' + i] = {
        label: 'Output ' + (i + 1)
      };
    }

    return data;
  }

  var operatorId = 0;

  $draggableOperators.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    opacity: 0.7,

    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
    zIndex: 1000,

    helper: function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var data = getOperatorData($this);
      return $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorElement', data);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var elOffset = ui.offset;
      var containerOffset = $container.offset();
      if (elOffset.left > containerOffset.left &&
        elOffset.top > containerOffset.top &&
        elOffset.left < containerOffset.left + $container.width() &&
        elOffset.top < containerOffset.top + $container.height()) {

        var flowchartOffset = $flowchart.offset();

        var relativeLeft = elOffset.left - flowchartOffset.left;
        var relativeTop = elOffset.top - flowchartOffset.top;

        var positionRatio = $flowchart.flowchart('getPositionRatio');
        relativeLeft /= positionRatio;
        relativeTop /= positionRatio;

        var data = getOperatorData($this);
        data.left = relativeLeft;
        data.top = relativeTop;

        $flowchart.flowchart('addOperator', data);
      }
    }
  });

});
```